# What is the complexity of this Power Set program?

Tags: python, set, complexity-theory

```
def powset2(seq):
    result = []
    if seq:
        head, tail = seq[:1], seq[1:]
        for smaller in powset2(tail):
            result.append(smaller)
            result.append(head + smaller)
    else:
        result.append([])
    return result
print((powset2([1,2,3,4])))
```

since we loop through half of it , is the complexity logn ?

Comment: I haven't look deeply into your code, but if you loop half of it everytime, it's definitely `O(n)`

Comment: @Netwave if this algorithm indeed generates a powerset, then I would be interested to know how one could achieve better than `2**N`, since for any set of size N, you will have 2**N sets (of various sizes). I think this is going to be worse than that even, `N*2**N` or something like that

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, yes, actually I think you are right. Because what I said is completely recursive.